# Merge two values into one cell in dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Say I have a dataframe like this:

```
   minute   values
0   1        3
1   2        4
2   1        1
3   4        6
```

And another one with a percentage set of values:

```
   minute   values
0   1        .30
1   2        .40
2   1        .10
3   4        .60
```

How could I fused the two dataframes together where the values (both count and percentage) are in the same cells for comparison like so...

```
   minute   values
0   1        3
             .30
1   2        4
             .40
2   1        1
             .10
3   4        6
             .60
```

I'm using Python3 and pandas. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `pd.concat` with the `keys` argument to combine:

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1, keys=['Count', 'Percentage'])
df

   Count        Percentage       
  minute values     minute values
0      1      3          1    0.3
1      2      4          2    0.4
2      1      1          1    0.1
3      4      6          4    0.6
```

You can then stack

```
df.stack(0)

              minute  values
0 Count            1     3.0
  Percentage       1     0.3
1 Count            2     4.0
  Percentage       2     0.4
2 Count            1     1.0
  Percentage       1     0.1
3 Count            4     6.0
  Percentage       4     0.6
```

Comment: Excellent! This handles exactly what I was trying to do even when dealing with a `MultiIndex`  dataframe. Would there be someway to leave the count values as integers without the concat converting them?

Answer (score 3):

Just need `concat`, then `sort_index` ,and `set_index`

```
pd.concat([df1,df2]).sort_index().set_index('minute',append=True)
Out[705]: 
          values
  minute        
0 1          3.0
  1          0.3
1 2          4.0
  2          0.4
2 1          1.0
  1          0.1
3 4          6.0
  4          0.6
```

Comment: Super simple! I'm a sucker for good one liners. This handles the simple dataframes very well, but gets a bit dicey when you get into `MultiIndex` ones.